# How to say 'never' in Mandarin Chinese?

Tags: mandarin

Research:

In here, https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20say%20never%20in%20mandarin 
It says that to say never, you say, "Cónglái méiyǒu", but another website, which is this one, http://eteacherchinese.com/Chinese-Dictionary/never-0 
says that you should say, "cónglái méi", so, how do you say 'never' in Mandarin Chinese?

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat, and to express 'never', depends on what you want to say. Look up never in a Chinese English dictionary, or get some ideas here: http://dj.iciba.com/never

Comment: And I was taught cónglái bu, which I find on line but mostly in songs.  Is that okay?

Comment: The difference between conglai bu and conglai mei(you) is one of time. Conglai bu means you never do (something). You never eat broccoli; you never gossip... etc. Conglai mei(you) means you have never done (something) up to now. For example, you have never learned Chinese before, but you may start tomorrow.

Answer (score 8):

There is seldom a one-on-one word translation that will work in all contexts. "从来没有 | cónglái méiyǒu" or "从来没 | cónglái méi" works if you're talking about something that has never happened up to the present time.

我从来没学过中文. (Wǒ cónglái méi xuéguò Zhōngwén - I have never learned Chinese.)

If you want to talk about the future, as in "something will never happen", you need a different expression altogether.

他永远不会来. (Tā yǒngyuǎn bù huì lái - He will never come.)

So, my suggestion is, if you're looking for a word meaning, at least provide a context.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: as a native speaker, I recommend the first one

Long answer:

You can use the first one in almost all scenarios ant it would sound okay. The second one is more commonly used with in a sentence before the verb, but if "Never" is the full response of a question, the first one would be better. I think this is because the second one is the shortcut for the first one, but in as a sentence itself, it would sound a bit unnatural to me, not that it is wrong or others won't understand you.

Answer (score 1):

从来没有 and 从来没 are the same thing

Answer (score 1):

我永远不会... would mean: I will never...

You use that when you would never do something.

Ex. 我永远不会玩足球。 （Translation: I will never play soccer.)

Answer (score 0):

绝不 or 绝对不会 or 绝对不干

I think 绝 more closely conveys the sense of "never".